# Lubridate error message - no such function: mdy

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Hi guys so I have 3 separate columns Month, DayofMonth, Year and I have been trying to use the lurbidate package to mutate these into a single "Date" column.

```
    yearly_data %>%
    mutate(flight_date =mdy(paste(Month,DayofMonth,Year))) %>%
    select(DepDelay,flight_date) %>%
    head(4)
```

However upon running the code I get the following error message

```
   Error in `collect()`:
    ! Failed to collect lazy table.
    Caused by error:
    ! no such function: mdy
```

Have also tried to reinstall the lubridate package
And package has also been loaded, thought it would work after updating r studio but still the same issue

Comment: In R, you install a package to get it on your computer, and then load it using `library(PACKAGE_I_NEED)` to use its functions in a session. Unclear if you did step 2.

Comment: Yep did that as well

Comment: try using `lubridate::mdy`

Comment: still the same error

Comment: From the error message `Error in `collect()`:` I would guess that you are doing an operation on a database table via `dbplyr`? If that is correct, note that `dbplyr` support only the most common R functions and unfortunately this does not inlude `lubridate::mdy`.

Comment: When posting a question, please be sure to state exactly which libraries you have loaded and from which package each function is called (as there are cases where a function name exists in more than one package).

Comment: @stefan  Can you be more explicit, i.e. is it the case that `dbplyr` does not recognize the `class` of objects returned from `lubridate::mdy` ?  That might allow the OP to add some class-conversion code.